# {{ csrf_token }} Não funciona

Tags: laravel, csrf

Estou desenvolvendo um form mas o csrf_token não funciona:

```
<form method="POST" action="/storeXML" class="form-inline">
    <div class="container">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <label class="">Url da integração</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a URL do XML">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

A rota está assim:

```
Route::post('/storeXML', 'IntegrationController@storeXml')->name('store');
```

E retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma ideia de como resolver esse tipo de problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta o `name=` do campo:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Creio que deveria ser:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

No entanto em Blade já existe o `@csrf`, use assim:

```
<form method="POST" action="/storeXML" class="form-inline">
    <div class="container">

        @csrf

        <label class="">Url da integração</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a URL do XML">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

### Antes do Laravel 5.6:

Até o Laravel 5.5 creio que deve-se usar o `csrf_field()` (não sei se é suportado em versões novas para dar retrocompatibilidade):

```
<form method="POST" action="/storeXML" class="form-inline">
    <div class="container">

        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <label class="">Url da integração</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a URL do XML">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```